# Xcode 7.3/Swift 2.2 bug? Code builds in simulator but shows errors on device

Tags: xcode, swift

The following swift code snippet compiles properly when built for the simulator, but if I select my iPhone 4 device (iOS 9.3.1) XCode complains:

```
if let result = (jsonobj["user"] ?? jsonobj["users"]!) {
    if let item = result["userID"] as Int {
        self.userID = item
    }
}
```

The error points to the 'result' variable on the second line and says "Value of optional type 'AnyObject?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"

The error makes no sense, as 'result' is unwrapped in the first line. Also, there was no problem before upgrading to XCode 7.3. As noted, if I switch to building for the simulator, the error goes away.

Should I post this as a bug? Does anyone have any insight?

**UPDATE**

When I first encountered this problem the device was not updated to the latest iOS build (9.3.1). I tried to make the compiler-suggested changes; this allowed the code to build but introduced errors when the simulator was chosen for a build. Also, the code crashed inexplicably when I ran it on the device.

I've subsequently updated the device to 9.3.1 and now the edited code runs without crashing, which enables me to continue development, but doesn't explain the difference with the simulator.

Next I created a new project and copied the erroneous code into the AppDelegate.swift file; the error appears again, however, it also appears for a simulator build. Making the recommended changes fixes the problem in both cases.

I will proceed by examining the build settings for both projects and see if there is a more specific cause for the difference in behavior between the device and the simulator.

Comment: The proper optional binding syntax is `if let item = result["userID"] as? Int {}`

Comment: @vadian only if result["userID"] is NOT Int?

Comment: @user3441734 I don't understand. This optional binding syntax implies to set `self.userID` only if the key `userID` in `result` exists and is of type `Int`. A value for a dictionary key is always `AnyObject?` by default unless the dictionary is declared more specific.

Comment: @vadian if result has type [String:Int]   .... than see my answer  // (3)

Comment: @user3441734 It's most unlikely that a JSON `user` dictionary is `[String:Int]` and even if it was, in this particular case the compiler doesn't know that.

Comment: Hm ...iPhone 4 device (iOS 9.3.1) ????? Is it true ???

Comment: This line is nuts: `if let result = (jsonobj["user"] ?? jsonobj["users"]!)` what is it even supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite like this:

```
if let result = jsonobj["user"] as? NSDictionary {
    if let item = result["userID"] as? Int {
        self.userID = item
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to provide an explicit type for 'result' in the first line:

```
if let result:AnyObject = jsonobj["user"] as? Int {
```